# How to skip validation on model update with nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update model with nested associations, skipping validations.
I have

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child_model_1
  has_many :child_models
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_model_1, :child_models
end
```

when I try to update ParentModel, I do next:

```
@parent_model.attributes = parent_model_params
@parent_model.save(validates: false)
```

This works fine for only ParentModel, but ignoring changes in child models. I read few other posts with the same problems, but it doesn't work for me. Please, help...

Answer (score 0):

If you do,

```
@parent_model.child_model1.attribute = 'some value'
@parent_model.save(validates: false)
```

It should update the parent as well as the child model attributes without invoking validations.

Comment: do you mean @parent_model.child_model1.attributes? so, if I had 5 nested models, I need to manually 'update' attributes for each and after save parent?